# Maplacejs is duplicating controls when updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using a jQuery plugin called Maplacejs (https://maplacejs.com/) to make Google Maps manipulation easier for me (I am new with this subject).

I first create a variable to set (initialize) Maplace:

```
var maplace = new Maplace({
    map_div: '#mappanel',
    controls_type: 'dropdown',
    controls_title: 'Select a point:',
    controls_position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
});
```

Then I create a function to load the locations in Maplace using ajax, when a certain date is selected in a dropdown menu:

```
function loadMap() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/ajax_getmap.php',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        timeout: 5000,
        data: { date: $('#dateselect').val() },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            maplace.SetLocations(data.locations, true);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)  {
            alert(errorThrown)
        }
    });
}
```

Here is an example of the locations array loaded with ajax:

```
{"locations":[
    {"lat":52.1,"lon":11.3,"title":"Title 1","html":"<h3>Content 1</h3>","zoom":8},
    {"lat":51.2,"lon":22.2,"title":"Title 2","html":"<h3>Content 2</h3>","zoom":8},
    {"lat":49.4,"lon":35.9,"title":"Title 3","html":"<h3>Content 3</h3>","zoom":8},
    {"lat":47.8,"lon":15.6,"title":"Title 4","html":"<h3>Content D2</h3>","zoom":8}
]}
```

And here is the code used to "call" the function (list of dates):

```
    $('#dateselect').selectmenu({
        style: 'dropdown',
        change: function(event, data) {
            loadMap();
        }
    });
```

The problem is: everytime this function is called, controls get duplicated in the map. Here is an example image after I call the function 3 times:

[image]

I already tried to create the maplace variable inside the ajax "sucess" event, and even set the variable to "null" or "undefined", but without sucess :(

Please, can you help me?

Comment: Please share your whole code. I can't see the handler for your select change event, or where is Maplace instantiated. Also, you can try crossposting your question at [StackOverflow Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com) to reach a broader audience

Comment: @amenadiel, I updated the question, thanks! Maplace is instantiated as a variable called "maplace". Sorry, I don't know spanish...

Comment: Oh, I saw "Mostrar Todos" and jumped to conclusions

Comment: It is portuguese :)

Answer (score 0):

For whom have the same problem, it was an issue and was fixed by latest version 0.2.8 (March 2017). Download last version [here](http://maplacejs.com/).